# Accessing only the last row using a database cursor

Tags: ruby, loops, cursor, database-cursor, oci8

Imagine a table with the following rows

| order | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 01:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 02:00:00 |
| 4 | 2021-01-01 03:00:00 |
| 5 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 2021-01-04 01:00:00 |
| 9 | 2021-01-04 02:00:00 |
| 10 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 |

I am using a cursor to loop through a database result one by one:

```rb
cursor = conn.parse("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC")
while result = cursor.fetch_hash()
    # Do some processing on the result
    # ...
end
```

I want to store the last processed row date into a variable to be used later for a different part of code. My solution is to do so:

```rb
last_date = ""

cursor = conn.parse("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC")
while result = cursor.fetch()
    last_date = result["date"]
    # Do some processing on the result
    # ...
end
```

Each iteration `last_date` is being updated and once the iteration ends it stores `2021-01-06 00:00:00`, which is what I want.

I'm curious is there a better or more elegant way of doing this? I can't think of an alternative.

Comment: What kind of object is `@cursor`, does `fetch_hash` return an enumerator?

Comment: @Kris `fetch_hash` is made available by ruby-oci8, it returns a single row as a hash [source](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/OCI8/Cursor#fetch_hash-instance_method)

Comment: Any reason you cant just execute `SELECT MAX(date) FROM table` since it appears you are processing every row anyway?

Comment: @engineersmnky I can run  `SELECT MAX(date) FROM table` first to get `last_date`. But afterwards I would also need to run `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC` because within that iterative logic I'm doing other things that further processes the result rows, which is an important part of the program. The example I have shown is a watered down version of what I'm trying to do to keep the focus on obtaining `last_date`.

Comment: Your solution appears quite good given your requirements. Voting to close as opinion-based.